# A list holding generic-inherited classes

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance

Assume I've got a generic abstract class:

```
ClassA<T> where T: ClassB
```

Now

```
public class ClassC: ClassB
```

and

```
public class NewClass: ClassA<ClassC>
```

I can create `NewClass` object with default constructor, but I cannot find a way to hold it in a generic collection of more general `ClassA<T>` objects.
The list defined like

```
List<ClassA<ClassB>>
```

can't hold `NewClass` objects. I'd like to keep differently derrived types in the same collection. Is there any way to do that in C#?
Also, I'd like to avoid using interfaces and virtual calls if possible.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why avoid interfaces? I'd rather avoid subclassing and prefer composition over inheritance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @DennisTraub I'm prototyping a game engine and interface calls are way too expensive for that purpose.

Comment: I assume using dynamic or an untyped list is out...  Why have all of the different generic base types?

Comment: @Tarec : interface calls are more expensive than plain instance calls, but if you are in this mind set, instance calls are more expensive than static calls. And static calls are more expensive than accessing compile-time constants. So should you create a compile-time constant game? Of course not! Interface calls are very unlikely to have any measurable impact on your performances.

Comment: @BrianMains ClassB is generally a base for objects to draw. NewClass is holding an internal collection of ClassC objects - this way it knows what kind of collection it holds and how to handle its items' properties (since I'm avoiding virtual calls on collection thousands of times per frame).
As think about it, it may be a good move to leave generic T type (drawing type) in my abstract ClassA definition, since I'm not accessing it from outside.

Comment: @Falanwe Instance calls can be inlined, increasing the call speed even up to 30 times. Also, I think that if something can be set at compile-time - it should be. That's what I'm trying to achieve - avoid ambiguity at runtime. I do know OOP rules and I'd never peck like that in every-day development, but in gamedev I'm trying to squeeze everything I can from c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is far simpler than your thing, it has to do with [parameter variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).
See these very simple classes:

```
public class Base {}

public class Derived : Base {}
```

A `List<Derived>` is **not** a `List<Base>`, and that's exactly the problem you're facing. Why is that? Because you can add `new Base()` to the latter, but not to the former. Similarly in your case, a `NewClass` is a `ClassA<ClassC>`, and `ClassC` inherits from `ClassB`, but a `NewClass` is **not** a `ClassA<ClassB>`.

You will very likely have to redesign your architecture, maybe with interfaces (which can be covariant or contravariant as you see fit).

**edit : some implementation ideas**

You can for instance define a covariant interface interface:

```
public interface IClassA<out T> where T : ClassB
```

Then a `List<IClass<ClassB>>` will be able to hold a `NewClass`

Or you can have `ClassA<T>` inherit from a non-genric base class `ClassA`.

```
public class ClassA
public class ClassA<T> : ClassA  where T : ClassB
```

Then you can store your `NewClass` in a `List<ClassA>`

Comment: I'm aware of it, but in f.e. in Java there were wildcards allowing to define subclasses for generic collections and I'm looking for similar solution in C#. You're right about redesigning - I'll do that if I'll be left out of options.

Comment: @Tarec It's not type safe at a conceptual level.  It's not a matter of C# having or not having a feature.  One cannot safely treat a `List` as if it were covariant without removing static typing.

Comment: Thank you both, the discussion is clearing my head a bit and it really seems that I started with some incorrect concept in the beginning.

Comment: Servy is right, treating collection classes as covariant is fundamentally wrong, because you can add items to them. It's the same as having covariant arrays, and that is a design flaw that often haunts developpers (less so now that we are hardly ever using "naked" arrays, but still).