# how to use a generic list for inherited classes?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I am stuck with a design and could use some advise if it is even possible in c# what I want.
To explain, I will put some code here

First, my base classes

```
public class TableBase
{
}

public class TableRepositoryBase
{
    public virtual void ReadFromDB(List<TableBase> list)
    {
    }
}
```

from here I want to inherit classed to use along with database tables,
for example `user` would look like this

```
public class TableUser : TableBase
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstNane { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class TableRepositoryUser : TableRepositoryBase
{
    public override void ReadFromDB(List<TableBase> list)
    {
        //base.ReadFromDB(list);

        // write code here to populate the list from the database
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new TableUser() { UserID = i, FirstNane = i.ToString(), LastName = i.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this in a simple test project, so I create a new windows form project, drop a datagridview on it, and then I setup a new datasource like this

[image]

So, now I can bind this to the datagridview, no problems there. I can also add the columns in designtime. This all seems ok.
Also, the designer created a BindingSource for me, called `tableUserBindingSource`

Now I would like to populate the list with values, using the method `ReadFromDB`
So I try this code

```
TableRepositoryUser tableRepositoryUser = new TableRepositoryUser();

List<TableUser> list = (List<TableUser>)tableUserBindingSource.List;
tableRepositoryUser.ReadFromDB(list);
```

But the last line does not compiles, the error is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ObjectListTest.TableUser>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ObjectListTest.TableBase>'   ObjectListTest  C:\Users\source\repos\ObjectListTest\ObjectListTest\Form1.cs    65  Active

And this seems clear to me, the class expects a list of `TableBase` and not of `TableUser`.

But, `TableUser` is derived from `TableBase` so should this not work like this ?
Do I need some generic list or something to get this working ?
If so, an example on how to use a generic list like this (derived classes) would be nice.
I have been looking at examples of generic list for some time but I just cannot find how to use them for this case.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489421/a-list-holding-generic-inherited-classes) which suggests that what I want is not possible. But this question is many years old, maybe by know there is some alternative way of doing what I want ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier That is a lot to read, give me some time to analyze these links

Comment: Can you create the list in the method? `public override List<TableBase> ReadFromDB( )`  Seems odd that you would want a list passed in to modify anyways.  Then you can return `newList.OfType<TableBase>().ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use these instead:

```
public interface ITableRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : TableBase
{
    public List<TEntity> ReadFromDb();
}

public class TableRepositoryUser : ITableRepository<TableUser>
{
    public List<TableUser> ReadFromDb()
    {
        var list = new List<TableUser>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new TableUser() { UserID = i, FirstNane = i.ToString(), LastName = i.ToString() });
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
var list = tableRepositoryUser.ReadFromDb();
```

And yeah, you need to make your own class to bound data to the UI.

Comment: Also, you may experiment and use other types to return (e.g. IEnumerable<TEntity> or IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity> or IList<TEntity>).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider having the list as a return type vs modifying an input object.

```
public override List<TableBase> ReadFromDB()
{
    List<TableUser> users = new List<TableUser>();

    // write code here to populate the list from the database
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        users.Add(new TableUser() { UserID = i, FirstNane = i.ToString(), LastName = i.ToString() });
    }
    return users.OfType<TableBase>().ToList();
}
```